# Hide btrfs .snapshots when mounting from other Linux

Tags: mount, fstab, btrfs, snapshot

I am mounting an old `btrfs` volume in a newer Linux.  The mount point is `/mnt/linux2`.  However, `btrfs`'s internal snapshots are shown as directories on the mounted disk, e.g.

```
/mnt/linux2/.snapshots/189/snapshot/usr/share/mythes/th_en_US_v2.dat
```

instead of just

```
/mnt/linux2/usr/share/mythes/th_en_US_v2.dat
```

**How can I mount the volume and** (probably through specifying mount options) show the `btrfs` partition as a flat, non-snapshotted filesystem, i.e. **hide the snapshots** and show only current versions of files?

Here is the line from `/etc/fstab`:

```
UUID=01234567-89ab-cdef-0123-456789abcdef /mnt/linux2 btrfs rw,relatime,ssd,space_cache,subvolid=5,subvol=/ 0 0
```

Comment: use `subvol=.snapshots/189/snapshot` instead of `subvolid=5,subvol=/`?

Comment: Actually, there are directories `.snapshots/$N/snapshot` for very many `$N`s. I wish to hide all snapshots, not pick a single one (I would not know which one, anyway, just want the newest).

Comment: So you are not trying to mount a specifc subvol/snapshot but the top-level one?

Comment: Yes, the "current" version, flattened.

Comment: I don't suppose there is a way to hide it? Because I think the .snapshot directory is not that internal but created by yourself?

Comment: You *could have* avoided this if you didn't use the top-level subvol for system root tree I think, but a subvol directly under it just like .snapshot, then you create snapshot of that subvol in .snapshot.

Comment: @TomYan The setup was created by the openSUSE installer, I never changed the default settings (wish I had avoided `btrfs` altogether). When booting that system, snapshots are not visible (by normal methods like `ls -l` I mean).

Comment: Hmm. Nevermind then. Maybe I just don't know btrfs (or OpenSUSE) enough.

Answer (score 2):

Tom Yan is correct, `.snapshots` is not a BTRFS internal directory, it's created and managed on OpenSUSE  (and possibly Ubuntu) by a piece of software called `snapper`.  Anything under that directory is a historical version, and the versions present in `@` are the current ones (and that is what is mounted by default as `/` during normal system operations).

The issue here is arguably not BTRFS, but the managers in charge of this aspect of OpenSUSE not thinking about the impacts on off-line maintenance of a system and instead focusing on making things as easy as possible for their developers to implement.

For future reference, you can avoid this crap by disabling snapshotting for the root filesystem during the OpenSUSE install.

Comment: Thanks. It is good to know who is to blame (`snapper`, apparently). Is that a solution, though? I cannot change the past! Can I mount it while hiding it?  I suppose as a workaround I could mount an empty `tmpfs` over `/mnt/linux2/.snapshots` but I would call that a workaround, not a solution, really.

Comment: There's not really a good solution to be honest.  It's non-trivial to convert the system away from the 'snapshot friendly' layout once it's installed.  The best option I can think of is to get a list of installed packages, copy out the config and user data, and reinstall it from scratch.